# make a standalone independent application out of a dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, web-applications, web

So, I've made a dynamic web project in Eclipse.It uses Jsp and servlets. Now I am told to make a standalone independent application for the same. I tried to google as to how it can be done. Most of them pointed me to use Export->Runnable jar file. But on doing so I can't find my dynamic web project in the Launch Configuration. Now how to make the standalone independent application ?

Comment: You can't create a standalone app out of a Java EE web app. A Java EE webapp needs a Java EE web container to run. The only thing you could do is to use an embeddable Java EE container. You should ask the person who told you to do that, without more information, what he wants and why. It seems he/she doesn't understand the technology you're using.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Okay ! Just tell me one thing. If I have just 1 page say JSP/HTML so now how can I make it as a standalone independent application. It doesn't have a Java class file. Is it possible ?

Comment: A JSP needs a JSP container to be executed. An HTML page can be served by any web server. If you just want to serve a static web page, using a Java EE container is overkill. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JB Nizet: So basically I have to make a standalone application for a search utility. It can be achieved using a Jsp page or Html page. Now how to do that  ?

Comment: What should this standalone application do with this static HTML page?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Basically I've used datatables for search utility.Now I've embedded it  in an Html page or even a JSP page. Now how to make it as a .exe file or standalone application with attractive GUI ? I'm really naive to this kind of stuff and really confused as to how to do it.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Also considering the noobnesss of the question, can it be done in an alternate way say with swings etc. ??

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. To me, a search utility that only consists in a single, static HTML page is not a search utility. It's a static web page.

Comment: Okay, so how to make a standalone independent application for a search functionality having an attractive GUI. ?

Comment: In Java, using JavaFx or Swing. Read tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Just 1 last naive question..is it possible to make a runnable jar out of a web application having jsp and servlets?

Comment: Yes. See my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing using embedded Jetty which means the application jar provides the web service without having to rely on a web server.